# Is this a good approximation for the initial velocity of the electron?

Tags: particle-physics, collision

I am studying the collision of a very fast proton ($E_p > 100$ MeV) on the electron of a metal (gold to be specific). Is it a good approximation to consider the initial velocity of the electron equal to zero?